# Undergraduate level numerical linear algebra course without dependency on linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, education

Is it possible to create an undergraduate level course on *numerical*/*applied* linear algebra *without* having linear algebra prerequisite?  Is there any examples of syllabus?

Comment: I suspect that if you look for a syllabus for an engineering-oriented linear algebra class, you'll find what you're looking for

Comment: The first course in linear algebra at many universities is an applied course without proofs. It often covers the mechanics of matrix manipulations without explaining why such manipulations work.

Comment: That being said: a course that covers the usual content of a numerical linear algebra course (for instance, eigenvalue-solving algorithms) would almost certainly have an introductory linear algebra course as a prerequisite.

Comment: What is the point of this?

Comment: The point of a numerical linear algebra course is to teach students numerical linear algebra which is of increasing importance in the applied side of computer science and data science (growing sectors for many universities).  The benefit of not having linear algebra as prerequisite is to allow faster pathways --- an average can take it in second year and do cool stuff with it soon after.  If numerical linear algebra requires linear algebra, many students will be taking it in the second semester of junior year.  That's a big difference.

Answer (score 2):

A recent example of a textbook (and related courses at Stanford and UCLA) that introduces linear algebra with significant applications and some topics that might be considered numerical linear algebra is *[Introduction to Applied Linear Algebra: Vectors, Matrices, and Least Squares](http://vmls-book.stanford.edu/)* by Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenbergh.

This book sacrifices a lot of topics from a traditional introduction to linear algebra course in order to get to least-squares problems and applications in data science.